# Node and edge colouring produce some problem - Graph vidualization

Tags: r, graph, igraph

A sample of my data set is as follows. I wrote the following code for network visualisation. My graph is made of an Adjacency matrix with a child and parent column. The label column has 3 levels as 0, 1, 2. I put labels as a vertex and edge attribute. The problem in the produced plot is, the colour of the parent node and the edge from it, should be the same because they follow the same rules, but in some case, it is not. why they are different?
[image]
the data :

```
row   row     child name        child       parent         parent name         vaccine    label          
40   39    MaryJoNabuurs 1.392302e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine 
 AstraZeneca     2
41   40  ElizabethDuncan 1.392297e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
42   41          7Rose75 1.392294e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     1
43   42      wh0careswh0 1.392336e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     0
44   43   T_ProudVeteran 1.392330e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     2
45   44   TweeetLorraine 1.392294e+18 1.392294e+18                 7Rose75  AstraZeneca     2
46   45         Norlaine 1.392288e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
47   46    elham95264575 1.393212e+18 1.392288e+18                Norlaine  AstraZeneca     1
48   47      soyfreemike 1.392387e+18 1.392288e+18                Norlaine  AstraZeneca     0
49   48          KMTCarr 1.392288e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
50   49     angela_petta 1.392283e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
51   50     lhoneyimhome 1.392272e+18 1.392218e+18          TweeetLorraine  AstraZeneca     2
```

```
net1 <- graph_from_data_frame(df %>% select("child","parent")) 
rel = get.adjacency(net1, sparse = FALSE)
graph = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(rel, mode="directed",weighted = TRUE)
graph = simplify(graph, remove.loops=TRUE)
graph
summary(graph)


vertex_attr(graph, "label") <- df$label
#Set edge attribute:
edge_attr(graph, "label") <- df$label




E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 2] <- '#B3DE69' #green
E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 1] <- '#80B1D3' #yellow
E(graph)$color[E(graph)$label == 0] <- '#FB8072'#purple

V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 2] <- '#B3DE69'
V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 1] <- '#80B1D3'
V(graph)$color[V(graph)$label == 0] <- '#FB8072'
g<-c('#B3DE69','#80B1D3','#FB8072')
plot(graph,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,
     vertex.frame.color=NA,vertex.label.color="black",
     edge.label = NA,
     vertex.size=3, usecurve=TRUE,
     edge.lwd=0.02,
     vertex.dist=10,vertex.label.dist=2,vertex.label.cex=0.9,
     pad=0.9,alpha=80,
     edge.arrow.size=.1)


legend("bottomleft",legend= c("Positive","Neutral","Negative"),
       col=g,pch=19,pt.cex=1.5,bty="n",
       title="Label category")

title(main="Visualization ", cex.main=1)
```

UPDATED:

I figured out the problem is using simplify. when I remove it, I get the correct plot. the problem is I don't want loop in my graph, what should I do instead of using simplify?

Comment: It would be much better if you provide `dput(df)`. Did you use `graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df)` to create graph object?

Comment: I exactly used net1 <- graph_from_data_frame(df %>% select("child","parent"))
rel = get.adjacency(net1, sparse = FALSE)

Comment: And then graph = graph_from_adjacency_matrix(rel, mode="directed",weighted = TRUE)
graph = simplify(graph, remove.loops=TRUE)

Comment: I really don't understand where the problem  could be?

Comment: Please put your code in your post and share the data you used for this question.

Comment: due to privacy I can't share the data.

Comment: But I provided a sample of dataset

Comment: A sample of dataset is Okey. I didn't see any connection between your plot and code in your post. Also, use `dput(df)` to share the sample of your data.

Comment: Just createa a minimal reproducible example and state what doesn't work & what would you want it to be. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I updated the code.there is nothing more to add

Comment: Thomas, you think where the problem could be?

Comment: I figured out the problem is using simplify.  when I remove it, I get the correct plot. the problem is I dont want loop, what I should I do?  instead of using simplify?

Comment: If you don't want to use `simplify`, you can use `df %>% select("child","parent") %>% unique()`

Comment: Becuse simplify causes this issue, I will check now your solution

Comment: No this cause even more problem and it would omit a large number nodes